# Calling lvcreate from inside the container hangs

Tags: lvm, docker, udev

I run a container. It has all the capabilities and mounts all the directories from root (except `/proc`). When I call `lvcreate` from inside of it I get:

```
# lvcreate -v -L104857600B -n vol1 default
Finding volume group "default"
Archiving volume group "default" metadata (seqno 17).
Creating logical volume vol1
Creating volume group backup "/etc/lvm/backup/default" (seqno 18).
Activating logical volume "vol1".
activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for default/vol1
Creating default-vol1
Loading default-vol1 table (252:4)
Resuming default-vol1 (252:4)
```

And the command hangs. I also get this in logs:

```
Sep 12 12:03:31 node3 systemd-udevd[12529]: Process '/sbin/dmsetup udevcomplete 23072978' failed with exit code 1
```

If I interrupt it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> I set, that the logical volume was created. I can also interrupt the command by issuing `dmsetup udevcomplete_all` from inside the same container. If I call `lvcreate` on the host it works normally and exits cleanly.

I believe, that this problem has something to do with udev cookies not being shared between container and host. I have no idea however, what exactly is lvm trying to do here and how to fix the problem.

I need this so that containerised kubelet can call flexvolume plugin that would be able to allocate logical volumes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm gonna say that you should avoid using `udev` in this case. This is easy enough to do with LVM, and LVM is entirely capable of handling volumes and device settling on its own.

Within your `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` file, you will find these lines:

```
udev_sync = 0

udev_rules = 0
```

As I have printed them there, set those values to zero and see if that clears it up. It will at the very least rule out `udev`. You will have to bring your volumes offline to make this change, as you will be switching from `udev` management to LVM management.

Comment: Hey @zefciu you still need help with this? I'm pretty confident that this can work (works in my lab), and it has very little impact risk.

Comment: Hi, thanks, sorry for the delay, I needed to recreate the environment which took some time.